# How to configure two P2P nodes on same channel using Hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, p2p, hyperledger-composer

> Current solution:

`1. I have a single node running on Hyperledger.`

`2. I have deployed my car-auction application on it.`

> Solution looking for:

I want my car-auction application to deploy on the second node and both nodes should be synced on the same channel.

Any suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically boils down to the network configuration that you define in Hyperledger Fabric.

This configuration is defined in two files:

1. [crypto-config.yaml](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#crypto-generator): Contains network topology
2. [configtx.yaml](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#configuration-transaction-generator): Defines genesis info and channel consortium

Considering your case, I assume your setup to be:

1. Single Organization
2. 2 peer nodes within this organization
3. 1 Orderer node
4. A single channel

So, you need to define network topology with an orderer and a single organization containing two peer nodes. You can find references for this complete setup at [build your first network docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) on fabric documentation.

Once you have that fabric setup ready, you take references from the [Composer Docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org). Over here, pay close attention to "connection-profile" file that you create. Since you want both these nodes to execute the car-auction chaincode, you'll need to define both of your peers as "endorsing peers" by setting "endorsingPeers" section to be "true" in the connection profile json file.

Follow the same compose reference to generate the PeerAdmin card. Now, when you install the car-auction bna file, it'll be installed on both the peers. Next, when you start the network, both the peer nodes will have their own chaincode container started up.

This way, you'll have two peer nodes connected on the same channel. And since they're on the same channel, they'll be in sync (regardless a peer is endorsing peer or not).

The same kind of setup goes for [the multi-org setup](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org).

Comment: Thank you @Mrudav Shukla. I will share my update once it is done.